# List all issues from an organization's private repo using github api v3

Tags: ruby, github-api

I'm trying to retrieve all issues from an org's private repo but not having much luck.

I'm using a ruby gem "github_api" but I've also tried just trying to access it using curl

So far I'm able to retrieve all issues that I'm assigned or that I'm subscribed but not all issues that exist for that particular repo.

Using the github_api gem (https://github.com/peter-murach/github), I've gotten this far

```
@github.issues.issues(:filter => "subscribed")
```

FYI: I'm the owner of the org and repo

Looking at the github api (issues) there doesn't appear to be a filter that will return what I need.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You should pop the solution into an answer and answer this yourself.

Comment: I tried but it said that I needed 100 points at least to answer my own questions (or something like that)

Comment: For me, I used omniauth and it is needed to add `:scope => "repo"`. Without the scope, I got 404.

Answer (score 14):

**This solution was provided by [Luis S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161661/user1161661), but he couldn't answer his own question because of not enough reputation. Moved it out out of his question for the sake of clarity. If you up-vote this answer don't forget to upvote his question :)**

---

just found the solution. when dealing with organizations. The organization is the actual github user.

So in case of the url:

https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/issues

replace :user by the org name and :repo by the repo name

As far as the github_api gem, use the organization name as the user

```
@github = Github.new :basic_auth => 'user:pass',
:org => 'org_name',
:user => 'org_name',
:repo => 'repo_name'
```

Comment: That answer, good sir, just saved me several hours of frustrating trial and error coding. Thank you!

Comment: Out of interest, what if the owner of the private repo is an individual...anyone come up against that? I'm finding it's still returning just my own issues as I'm the repo owner, when really I want ALL issues :(...

Comment: You are the MAN! I never would've guessed /repos/:org_name/:repo/issues instead of /repos/:username/:repo/issues as the API puts it. Thanks again!!