# List of Repos (Public and Private) for an Organization on Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-api

I am trying to get a list of all repos associated with an organization using the github api gem in my rails application. I use omniauth to authenticate a user and then I am able to access a list of their organizations as well as a list of the user's repos but I am trying to get a list of repos for the user's organizations (which they have administrative access to).

There was one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755257/list-all-issues-from-an-organizations-private-repo-using-github-api-v3) on stackoverflow that seemed hopeful and it answered my question for accessing info for an organization's repo that I already have the name of but what about repos that I don't have a name for?

Any ideas how to list all repos for an org using the github api gem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you able to fetch the info using plain curl? E.g. try:

```
curl -u "your_username" https://api.github.com/orgs/:your_organization/repos?type=private
```

(this should list only private repos, substitute `private` with `all` to list all repos, as per the API docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories).

If this works, then you are just having trouble making it work using the ruby library?

If you don't know which organizations a user belongs to, use this API to find out: http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-user-organizations

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you helped me find the solution. Peter Murach answers how to use the gem to solve this [here](https://github.com/peter-murach/github/issues/53). After authenticating, this will get you a list of all private and public repos for an organization `github.repos.list :org => 'org-name'`

Comment: In my org we have hundreds of repos. To clean them up we had to list all of them with last commit date and committer. Python script for that [here](https://gist.github.com/tilayealemu/56fd45aab4f6943fac8447cc2019595c).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this using GitHub's GraphQL API:

```
{
  organization(login: "<my-org-name>") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          name
          isArchived
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found [GitHub's GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/overview/explorer) to be really useful for quickly figuring this out.

One option for execution is GitHub's `gh` CLI which can run this query and you can then manipulate the output with `jq` or something.

Note that you'll need to implement pagination for more than 100 repos :)